# Hide Image in other View Controller by pressing a button

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, xcode7

I have main ViewController (No.1) that contains Button and another ViewController (No.2) that contains Image (Set Default in (void)viewDidLoad as hidden) .

I need when pressing this Button (in No.1) to go to ViewController No.2 and show image in ViewController (in No.2) ???!!

I declared ((IBAction)ViewButton:(id)sender) in ViewController No.1
I declared (@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *image) in ViewController No.2

Comment: use prepare for segue!!! to send a bool value, and use that bool value to hide the image view

Comment: It really depends if you are talking two simultaneous views such as in a splitviewcontroller, or the button opens the second view. You can pass with segue and prepareForSegue, or use a global variable and an NSNotification to update.